# What is difference between dbcontext.Add and dbcontext.AddObject

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am beginner at WPF. I want to know that what is difference between `dbcontext.Add` and `dbcontext.AddObject`.

```
private void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        Name employee = new Name();
        employee.Name1 = "Test";
        dataContext.Names.AddObject(employee);
}
```

I want to achieve this `dbcontext.AddObject()`. But I get an error:

> 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' does not contain a definition for 'AddObject' and no extension method 'AddObject' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WpfApplication9\WpfApplication9\MainWindow.xaml.cs 49  31  WpfApplication9`

Also suggest which one is better. Thank you.

Comment: This has nothing to do with WPF. It is related to Entity Framework.

Answer (score 16):

Actually you are talking about `AddObject` method of `ObjectSet<TEntity>` class which was used by old `ObjectContext`. But since Entity Framework 4 we have `DbContext` class (which is a wrapper over old `ObjectContext`). This new class uses `DbSet<TEntity>` instead of old `ObjectSet<TEntity>`. New set class has method `Add`.

So, back to differences. Old implementation invoked `AddObject` method of `ObjectContext`:

```
public void AddObject(TEntity entity)
{
    Context.AddObject(FullyQualifiedEntitySetName, entity);
}
```

New implementation does same thing (see action parameter):

```
public virtual void Add(object entity)
{
    ActOnSet(() => ((InternalSet<TEntity>) this).InternalContext.ObjectContext.AddObject(((InternalSet<TEntity>) this).EntitySetName, entity),  
              EntityState.Added, entity, "Add");
}
```

As you can see same `ObjectContext.AddObject` method is called internally. What was changed - previously we just added entity to context, but now if there is state entry exists in ObjectStateManager, then we just changing state of entry to `Added`:

```
if (InternalContext.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(entity, out entry))
{
    entry.ChangeState(newState); // just change state
}
else
{
    action(); // invoke ObjectContext.AddObject
}
```

Main goal of new API is making `DbContext` easier to use.

Comment: Please note that the problems the OP has are the result of calling AddObject on the DbSet<T> and not on the context. Maybe you can elaborate your answer with showing how to use both, by calling ObjectContext.AddObject("Names", nameEntityToAdd) and DbContext.Names.Add(nameEntityToAdd)

Answer (score 1):

Call AddObject on the ObjectContext to add the object to the object context.

Do this when the object is a new object that does not yet exist in the data source.

When you create a new object that is related to another object in the object context, add the object by using one of the following methods:
Call the Add method on the EntityCollection and specify the related object.

Answer (score 0):

The short of it seems to be that they're roughly the same.  I found this blog post kinda short and to the point:

http://blog.cincura.net/232485-someentityset-addobject-vs-addtosomeentityset-methods/

You can also have a look at the MSDN, but in this particular case I found it to be a little cryptic.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.addobject.aspx

Your error is indicating that the method isn't available. I find this happens when you switch to a new version of Entity Framework. You'll need to go through and change all of your Method calls to us `Add`

If there is some core reason why you want to use AddObject, then explain in more detail what your needs are here so someone can better help you.