# context.SaveChanges does not save changes without any error

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, visual-studio

I'm trying to add one object to database table using this code, in my console application:

```
using (var context = new Database1Entities())
      {
        var number = new Numbers()
        {
            Num=15
        };
        context.Numbers.AddObject(number);
        context.SaveChanges();
        Console.WriteLine(number.Id);
        Console.ReadLine();
      }
```

My model:

[image]

Connection string:

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="Database1Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;integrated security=True;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

packages.config:

```
<packages>
   <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.0" targetFramework="net40-Client" />
</packages>
```

but it does not add any thing to database and whenever it runs, it returns `1` as `Id` of stored `Number`.

Comment: What does the connection string look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As *Abhay Prince* said: **There is no any syntactical or logical error or mistake in this code.**

**Problem**: I should say that always changes which program do on *mdf* file was on file that automatically copied to *bin/debug* folder; so when I check my *mdf* file that is reachable in Visual Studio, it does not have any changes affected by application.

Answer (score 1):

There is no any syntactical or logical error or mistake in your code. It should work perfectly, if it is not giving desired output, try clean your project or restart your Visual Studio may be it is due to cache or log data.

Try restart your Visual Studio and let we know if it works correct or not..

Comment: Then I'm sorry.. I can't see any problem. THis code is working fine in my system.. Try using 
context.AddToNumbers(number) 
if it works..

Comment: Have you found any answer or not? 
context.AddToNumbers(number)   is it worked or not?

Comment: I tried `AddToNumbers` but no thing changed! I wanna to upgrade my EF to 6.1!

Comment: Can you send me your complete .cs code and table structure 
my email id is abhayprince@outlook.com

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
context.Numbers.AddObject(number);
context.Entry(number).State = EntityState.Added;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: `Add` method does not exists!

Comment: Which version EF you are using..?Have tried this ?context.Numbers.AddObject(number);context.Entry(number).State = EntityState.Added;
context.SaveChanges();

Comment: Is your Id set to Identity column..? Try context.AddToNumbers(number);as suggested by Abhay Prince.

Comment: it is identity and auto increment. I also tried `AddToNumbers` but no success! I'll upgrade EF to latest version.

Comment: Try if not you can move to latest version.My suggestion is to always go with latest one.:)

Comment: You can use now context.Numbers.Add(number); and check

Comment: despite that I use EF6 but I can't use `Add` method! also I found answer finally! thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correct
[What is difference between dbcontext.Add and dbcontext.AddObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231889/what-is-difference-between-dbcontext-add-and-dbcontext-addobject)
then you need to set manually that the context has been changed before it can save to database.

If you instead use

```
context.Numbers.Add(number);
```

The context should automatically set that the context has changed and the savechanges should work.

Comment: AddObject method is same as Add.
Add methode is introduced in EF5

Answer (score 0):

put SaveChanges() in try catch
it captures the SaveChanges() error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).