# AddObjects() doesnt appear in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, collections

```
 NorthwindEntities n = new NorthwindEntities();
```

I create an entity model from an existing database, EF also generate context class. I use it. Why don't I see method `AddObjects()`?

I can call only `Add()`

```
n.Orders.Add(MyOrder);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not specify which Entity Framework version you are using.
Actually what happens here you are using Entity Framework version 4.0+.
Upto EF4.0 there was method used AddObject().Later versions using Add() method to add object in context.

You can check following link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj592676.aspx

Comment: I use Entity Famework  6.0.0

Comment: Can you please specify have you any special need to use AddObject in your scenario.?? Because Add() method is newer than AddObject method of entity framework

Answer (score 2):

This is because the current version of EF uses a `DbContext` instead of an `ObjectContext`. You are probably looking for `AddRange()`, which practically does the same. You can find a good tutorial [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/dbcontext-vs-objectcontext.aspx).

Comment: there isn't difference between this methods?

Comment: In most cases not, but if you provide some more code I can tell you for sure. If you are willing to add multiple entities at once, you should probably just stick to `AddRange`.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are working with `DBContext` and `DBSet<TEntity>` classes. The `AddObject` method belongs to`ObjectSet<TEntity>` class which was used by old `ObjectContext`. But since Entity Framework 4 we have `DbContext` class (which is a wrapper over old `ObjectContext`). This new class uses `DbSet<TEntity>` instead of old `ObjectSet<TEntity>`. New set class has method `Add` and not `AddObject` but is used for the same action.

I you want to know more about this check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231889/what-is-difference-between-dbcontext-add-and-dbcontext-addobject) and this [page](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/dbcontext-vs-objectcontext.aspx).