# AddObject in Entity Framework not working (MVC 4)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm coding a web by MVC4. I use Entity Framework and Visual Studio Express 2012 for web. When I code Insert for Student, have a problem:

```
demoMVCEntities db = new demoMVCEntities();
n412_Student _newStudent = new n412_Student();
_newStudent.Student_FirstName = _fname;
_newStudent.Student_LastName = _lname;
_newStudent.Student_Phone = _phone;
_newStudent.Student_Email = _email;
_newStudent.Student_Province = _provinces;
db.n412_Student.AddObject(_newStudent);
```

AddObject is red underlined. Message Error:

> "'System.Data.Entity.DBSet' does not contain a definition for 'AddObject' and no extension method 'AddObject' accepting a first argument of type...."

Please help me.. thanks..!

Answer (score 1):

`AddObject` is a  method of the `ObjectContext` but in newer versions of Entity Framework you are typically working against a [`DbContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx).This new class uses [`DbSet<TEntity>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset(v=vs.113).aspx) instead of old `ObjectSet<TEntity>`. New set class has method [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.add(v=vs.113).aspx). So, as the exception said, you are working with a [`DBSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset(v=vs.113).aspx) object (`n412_Student`), that have an `Add` method. You need to do this:

```
db.n412_Student.Add(_newStudent);
```

If you want to see the difference between `AddObject` and `Add` methods, you can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231889/what-is-difference-between-dbcontext-add-and-dbcontext-addobject)

Comment: No problem ;), If you think my answer helped you to solve your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.