# Adding multiple items using Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I have been looking at this problem for a while.  I am trying to save multiple items in a single call.  This is my code:

```
    public Response<List<Transaction>> SetTransactions(List<Transaction> transactionList)
    {
        try
        {
            var responseData = new Response<List<Transaction>>
            {
                Status = Enums.Status.Success,
                DisplayMessage = DisplayMessageConstants.CardTransactionSuccess
            };

            foreach (var transaction in transactionList)
            {   
                EntityContext.Transactions.Add(transaction);
            }

            EntityContext.SaveChanges();

            return responseData;

        }
```

I am using the code first approach and Entity 5.0 in .net 4.5.

I have found several examples of this issue and all of them state the following should work:

**EntityContext.Transactions.AddObject(transaction).**

The issue is that I don't seem to have the option of AddObject.  What am I missing?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Not getting an error - The option is just not available.

Comment: Just updated the question - I ended up copying my single add method - the question now refects the correct method,..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [What is difference between dbcontext.Add and dbcontext.AddObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231889/what-is-difference-between-dbcontext-add-and-dbcontext-addobject)
The reason you aren't getting the option of AddObject is just an Entity Framework thing. The answer I referenced above says that since version 4.0 this has changed. You should still be getting the result you want with the code you posted, is it giving you an error?

Comment: Getting an identity error from the database when its trying to insert.  From what I can tell, its not getting multiple unique primary keys from the database.

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you trying to insert a duplicate record when there's  a unique constraint? I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. It sounds like you're having more of a data issue than a problem with your code.

Comment: Getting a UniqueConstraint violation.  These are all new records where the primary key is being generated by the database.   It works fine for a single record but not for multiple new records.

Comment: The code you posted will only do one at a time. Do you have another snippet where you've modified it to insert multiple records or are you just calling this function over and over? Just wondering what's being done differently when you insert multiple.

Comment: Been one of those days.....I copied the wrong snippit.... My question now reflects the method I am using.

Comment: Is it possible that your primary key is not being generated by the database? It's all I can think of to cause that. According to the MSDN site, "Before SaveChanges is called, the Entity Framework generates a temporary key value for every new object. After SaveChanges is called, the key value is replaced by the identity value assigned by the data source when a new row is inserted." But if your DB isn't generating it, you'll only get one record saved before you violate the unique constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out - The code works fine - there was a weird constraint on the DB table that was casuing all the issues.  Thanks to everyone who looked and tried to help.